# Need to create a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to rename folders across multiple directories.  Directories look like:

```
101 Test
6982 Broad
5421 Scope
```

Within each of these directories, there are subfolders such as:

```
Correspondence
Billing and Invoices
Motions & Orders
```

and so forth....

I need to rename the the above subfolders in each of the above directories to be:

```
CORR
BILL
MOTS
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please regard that Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service, so you have to try it on your own and in case of trouble return to here with a specific question and providing a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Please take the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create the script not in the sub folder, but the folder above it.
Example:

```
ren Example Example1
```

In your case:

```
@echo off

ren Correspondence CORR
```

This should do the trick. Best of luck.

Comment: If the folder name has two words like "Legal Research", is there something extra I need to do?

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted if my answer was right. Also, OP, if my answer is right, click the check below the score. About your other question, try putting it in quotes- `ren "Legal Research" LEGAL`

Comment: Didn't know to post a check.  This is my first time ever on this site.   Hopefully, I got it right now.    Both of your answers were spot on.   I have one last question if you are willing to oblige.   Folder is named Motion - Orders or Motion & Orders and I want to rename it to just MOTS.

Comment: It should just be `ren "Motion & Orders" MOTS`.

Comment: Thank you.  I had two commands in the Batch file.  ren "Motions & Orders" MOTS and ren "Motions-Orders" MOTS.     It was only changing one of them.  I then realized it wasn't going to do the 2nd one because MOTS now already existed. You have been extremely helpful and I really appreciate it.